# How to create tiktok record Button Animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am create an app that allow users to record videos and want to create a record button similar to tiktok, I have already create the prerecord button but I don't know how to add the animation.

```
 Widget recordbutton() {
return Container(
  width: 80,
  height: 80,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    border: Border.all(
        width: 4, color: !isRecording ? Colors.white : Colors.red),
  ),
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: !isRecording ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
    ),
  ),
);}
```

On long press the button should animate like the gif below

[image]

Comment: you can use InkResponse, but you have to manipulate it or use different approach see this example  https://youtu.be/NNurG9HqRd0?t=687

Answer (score 0):

you u can use [rive](https://rive.app) for animations like that.
You can see the example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-m0elXGQPLo